# How to use AT commands in C language

Tags: c, sms, gsm, at-command

My project consists of a part that has to send sms via GSM modem using AT commands. I have learnt using these commands via hyper terminal and putty. What I want is that how can I use these AT commands in my "C" code built on eclipse.
Please guide me!

Comment: AT commands finaly calls a perticular function.You can try making a function which will parse the AT command.Parsing will include capturing name,value or parameters given after "AT" then try making a switch statements which will call a perticular case based on parsed command.

Comment: you can try opening the same IP/port you used for putty and write the AT commands to that port

Answer (score 1):

It's going to depend on your OS. I'm assuming the modem is connected to the computer via serial or USB or something like that. On most Unix it would be something like this:

```
int modem_fd = open("/path/to/modem", O_ASYNC);
char modem_command[] = "ATDT5551234"
write(modem_fd, modem_command, sizeof(modem_command));
```

You can also get similar functionality with fopen() and fwrite(), which are part of stdio.h.

Comment: Also remember that since most modems emulate a serial port you'll have to setup the correct baudrate, data / stop-bits and so on using tcattr's.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the device as a file and do I/O operations. We ca send AT commands similar to write data to file.But data must be in mentioned form by the device manufactures.